# how to see how many users are online using epoch time?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

i am having problem of see who's online and don't have any idea how to see who's online.what i am doing is updating mysql database using time(); whenever user log in or refreshes the page.

Then, lastactivity gets filled with epochtime for eg : 1387806657 or 1287373415.
After that i select the lastactivity from database and use this condition but nothing happens.

```
<?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT lastactivity FROM users WHERE lastactivity!=0");            
while($rahul = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$last = $rahul['lastactivity'];
echo $last;
}
?>
</br>
<?
if ($result < time()-3600) 
{
$hello = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $hello;
}
else
{
echo "ERROR!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decide that any acticity in a 30 second interval from now means "online"

```
$early = time()-30;
$res = mysql_query("SELECT username,lastactivity FROM users WHERE lastactivity > $early") or die( mysql_error() );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
{
  echo $row['username'].' is online.<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about going to the source and parsing or watching your Apache log to see which pages are being loaded?

Comment: You said, "...and don't have any idea how to see who's online."  I was just providing you with one more way to have an idea of who's online.  It's a good way to look at the Apache log.  It actually gives you more information in some ways.  Unless of course you need to know who exactly is online, but that's not what you said exactly.